# Applozic user list creation and deletion in iOS

Tags: ios, applozic

I am using the Applozic iOS client in my app for the chat messaging.
I want to delete the users list and start creating new users.

1. How to delete the existing user list in Applozic chat application ?
2. How to create a new users list with default password ?
3. How do the newly created users change their default password after they login to the app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to delete the existing user list in Applozic chat application ?

- If you are looking to start fresh, you can create a new application from Applozic Dashboard https://www.applozic.com and use the new application key in project.

> How to create a new users list with default password ?

- Uninstall the previous installation and install it again with the new application key.

> How do the newly created users change their default password after
>   they login to the app ?

- User's password need to be maintained at your application end and you can pass the same or some generated token to Applozic SDK and configure your server end point url for verifying the token.
  https://www.applozic.com/docs/configuration.html#access-token-url